# modulus bug in R

Tags: r, modulo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Just noticed this bug in R. I'm guessing it's the way 0.6 is represented, but anyone know exactly what's going on?

According to R:

```
0.3 %% 0.2 = 0.1
0.4 %% 0.2 = 0
0.5 %% 0.2 = 0.1
**0.6 %% 0.2 = 0.2**
0.7 %% 0.2 = 0.1
0.8 %% 0.2 = 0
```

What's going on?

Comment: [FAQ 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: that should really be an answer, not just a comment... +1.

Comment: A new tag "r-faq-7.31" looks more and more useful to me...

Comment: @Gsee, I wouldnt call this a duplicate.  The reasoning behind it is the same, but if someone is googling the problem, they wouldnt necessarily find the other answer.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, that's why we close as a duplicate.  They'll find this one when they search for modulo and it will link to the main Q that it is a duplicate of.  Closing and deleting are not the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to @joshua Ulrich's comment

from `?'%%'`

> %% and x %/% y can be used for non-integer y, e.g. 1 %/% 0.2, but the results are subject to representation error and so may be platform-dependent. Because the IEC 60059 representation of 0.2 is a binary fraction slightly larger than 0.2, the answer to 1 %/% 0.2 should be 4 but most platforms give 5.

also similar to why we get this

```
> .1 + .1 + .1 == .3
[1] FALSE
```

as @Ben Boker pointed out, you may want to use something like

```
> 3:8 %% 2 / 10
[1] 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.1 0.0
```

Comment: and (as pointed out in a now-deleted answer) the 'solution' is to use integer arithmetic if possible: `6 %% 2` instead of `0.6 %% 0.2`

Comment: Yep, ended up doing that. Thanks.

Comment: this seems to work: `Mod <- function(n,m){
  if( m >= n ) return(n);
  n.digits <- nchar(strsplit(paste(n),".",fixed=T)[[1]][2]);
  div <- floor(n/m);
  rem <- n - (div * m);
  return(round(rem,n.digits))
}
`